# Running Angular 6 with PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, angular, angular6

I everybody as I'm new to Angular 6. As I needed the code to insert the data from PHP MySQL
As I have followed to insert the data using AngularJS and it was successfull

I had installed node js, angular CLI and soon..

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>softAOX | Insert Data Into Database using Angular JS with PHP Mysql</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1 align="center">Insert Data Into Database using Angular JS with PHP Mysql</h1>
<div ng-app="sa_insert" ng-controller="controller">
<label>Name</label><input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" class="form-control"><br/>
<label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email" ng-model="email" class="form-control"><br/>
<label>Age</label><input type="text" name="age" ng-model="age" class="form-control"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="insert" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="insert()" value="Insert">
</div>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("sa_insert",[]);
app.controller("controller", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.insert = function(){
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: {
                name: $scope.name,
                email:$scope.email, 
                age:$scope.age
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });

        // $http.post(
        // "insert.php",
        // {'name':$scope.name, 'email':$scope.email, 'age':$scope.age}
        // ).success(function(data){
        //  alert(data);
        //  $scope.name = null;
        //  $scope.email = null;
        //  $scope.age = null;
        // });
    }
});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
Accept");
session_start();


// echo 'sdf'; die;
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "angular_js");
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
if(count($info) > 0)
{
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->name);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->email);
  $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->age);
  $query = "INSERT INTO insert_emp_info(name, email, age) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$age')"; // Insert Query
  if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
  {
    echo "Insert Data Successfully";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Failed";
  }
}
?>
```

Error 404 Not Found

> Cannot POST /insert.php

Kindly suggest me with this issue

Comment: This is not angular 6 application. You have developed this in angularJs.

Comment: Yes!. Your right as I kindly requesting you how am I supposed to save data @Shashikant Devani

Comment: I needed to migrate from AngularJS to Angular 6 @Shashikant Devani

Comment: First replace your url with `url : API URL` instead of `url: "insert.php"`

Comment: I don't know `angularjs` application migration to `angular 6` is possible or not. So i can not help you for that, Sorry.